# Change the mouse wheel scrolling acceleration

Tags: mouse, macos

I am new Mac user and I don't really like the Magic Mouse so I reverted to a good old 3 button mouse with a scroll wheel.

When I turn the wheel slowly, it only scrolls pixel per pixel (or per two pixels)
If I turn the wheel more quickly, it scrolls nearly line by line. There is a kind of scroll wheel acceleration where the amount scrolled for each wheel step depends on the rotation speed of the wheel.

This behavior is not present in Windows where you always scroll a few lines per wheel step.

Is there a way to disable this behaviour or to tweak it in Mac OS X Lion?

Comment: Does the mouse's vendor have drivers/software for OS X? For example, Microsoft's Intellipoint mice come with a System Preferences pane that allows you to tweak scrolling speed: http://i.imgur.com/GJ4SM.png

Comment: What brand is it?

Comment: It is a generic Dell mouse, but every mouse I have tested have the same slow scrolling acceleration

Comment: If Chrome is your main browser you can use [this extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/khpcanbeojalbkpgpmjpdkjnkfcgfkhb) to add this feature to chrome. However, with this extension enabled you should only use the mouse to scroll in lion. No magic mouse or magic trackpad.

Comment: @koiyu Where did you get this ?

Comment: @jokoon I got it through the vendor's product's download page (in my case [Microsoft/Natural Ergonomic Desktop 7000](http://www.microsoft.com/hardware/en-us/d/natural-ergonomic-desktop-7000)). (edit: interesting, the `en-us` page does not have the link for IntelliType, but [`fi-fi` page](http://www.microsoft.com/hardware/fi-fi/d/natural-ergonomic-desktop-7000), which I used, does)

Comment: This behavior is really annoying. Seems like Apple wants to discourage people to use mice instead of his trackpad...

Answer (score 22):

Hope you're still reading - I highly recommend one of the third party mouse managers like [SteerMouse](http://plentycom.jp/en/steermouse/) or [USB Overdrive](http://www.usboverdrive.com/USBOverdrive/Information.html) or [ControllerMate](http://www.orderedbytes.com/controllermate/).

I found the arch of the Magic Mouse just too low and went back to the old reliable Logitech MX Revolution, but I will never install Logitech software again without an excellent reason. These packages will let you configure all of the buttons and SteerMouse (haven't verified for the other two) will definitely let you specify linear or accelerated wheel scrolling with variable degree of acceleration.

Comment: I'm also new to MacOS. I totally agree we should never install contructor drivers for this kind of device. But I'm used to opensource softwares. Is there really people buying applications for tunning their mice (in Apple world) ?

Comment: I bought SteerMouse. As a developer I am happy to support another developer who makes my experience better. Open Source is a fine idea, but sometimes you just need one guy with a vision.

Comment: I undestand your opinion. I personnaly prefer freely contribute to projets than giving money. This is the original idea of opensource.

Comment: is there any open source program? because I absolutely refuse to pay money just to slow down scrolling in finder.

Comment: Shrug. You see some value in it but won't pay for it? Use inbuilt preferences or install the vendor's drivers - you paid for those with the hardware.

Comment: Thank you for the SteerMouse recommendation. I had an issue with LCC in El Capitan where the mouse scroll wheel would accelerate in Chrome dev tools (i.e. 8 increments when adjusting numeric values with the mouse wheel in the Style tab). Un-installed LCC and installed SteerMouse and was able to map all MX Revolution buttons - including the search button override to middle click. My WebStorm issue where back and forward buttons could not be bound in the IDE were automagically fixed. Well worth the $20 license price!

Comment: I've developed an app that does that among other things. The app is not free but that specific feature is free and will always be free. Check out Smooze in my answer.

Comment: SteerMouse is a godsend. I've been suffering with the Logitech drivers since getting the MX Anywhere 2.

Answer (score 19):

After many years of frustration with macOS & wheel mice, I've developed Smooze.
Disabling the scroll acceleration and setting the number of lines you want to move on each tick are free features.

[image]

[Smooze website](http://smooze.co)

Comment: Hi bro, what are the exact settings needed to make scrolling on Chrome **identical** to that of Windows? Would be great if there's a checkbox where the user can just tick to make it work like as per Windows...

Comment: Adding presets is high on my to do list. Regarding the Windows Chrome settings, I never tried to compare the two.. Windows 10 will defiantly be one of the presets, though.

Comment: Smooze breaks scrolling in XQuartz :(

Comment: If someone comes here in 2022, there's LinearMouse. It's free and open source. Not quite as fancy as Smooze, but free > $20

Comment: @LordZsolt Awesome. I am using LinearMouse with scrolling acceleration 0.33 and scrolling speed 13, and it feels very much like on Windows 10.

Answer (score 10):

[USB Overdrive](http://www.senlick.com/html/01.01.html) changes the default scrolling behavior so that single ticks of a scroll wheel scroll in larger increments.

It also has an option to for example make a single tick always scroll a single line. It also supports changing the tracking (but not scrolling) acceleration, like SmoothMouse or MouseAcceleration.prefPane.

[image]

Comment: This works well, but it is "beg-ware" on bootup and whenever entering the dialog above, and costs $20 to register.

Comment: This does not work for the trackpad.

Comment: @kmarsh Yeah otherwise known as shareware? Do you not understand how that works?

Comment: Thank you for your concern @tubedogg, I am familiar with shareware, and other dying paradigms.

Comment: Clearly familiar enough to feel entitled to have the "beg" screen go away without actually purchasing the software instead of using it for free forever.

Comment: This app does not solve the issue of single step scroll using the wheel. Even after setup to 3 lines per scroll, it scrolls a single pixel instead of 3 lines. SteerMouse app saved my life.

Answer (score 9):

There is now a free program called DiscreteScroll - https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/262329/221420 - it will make it so that one mouse wheel tick scrolls 3 lines.

Comment: This answer should have more upvotes!

Comment: @HimanshuP Hear hear.

Answer (score 8):

https://mousefix.org/ -- Try this, I was facing the same issue. Sometimes wanted to use trackpad and a normal mouse together. It has a setting "Invert Direction" too. I am sure you will not go anywhere else after using this.

I am on mac Mojave 10.14.6. Its FREE!

Comment: As a long time Linux user, this has made my transition a lot easier.

Comment: This is one of the few up-to-date free options. Saved me some nerves!

Comment: As mentioned in the comment above, this is up-to-date and works perfectly for anybody migrating from Windows. (I am using it with the Microsoft Sculpt Ergonomic Mouse).

Answer (score 4):

If you have logitech mouse then you can try installing Logitech Control Center for Macintosh® OS X http://www.logitech.com/en-us/support/3129?section=downloads&bit=&osid=35

Answer (score 4):

The application found here fixes the issue:

https://github.com/davekeck/DisableExtremeScrollAcceleration

Comment: doesn't seem to work for me... should I log off and log on again, or restart applications ?

Comment: check out this for Mavericks: http://superuser.com/questions/710926/disabling-scroll-wheel-acceleration-on-os-x-mavericks

Answer (score 1):

[SmoothMouse](http://smoothmouse.com/) donationware works great for me on OS X El Capitan 10.11.3

Comment: At least try to bother to read the title, this app only works for cursor acceleration, and not WHEEL SCROLLING acceleration...

Comment: Thanks for pulling me up on this (if a little aggressively) @Facundo. I installed this and was convinced it had fixed the scroll wheel, but have since discovered that it must have been something else, as I have lost the effect.

Comment: Sorry for the aggressively part @Chris

Comment: Not at all thanks @FacundoPedrazzini and thanks for correcting my answer.

Comment: SmoothMouse does not work in OS X Sierra anymore, but you can control mouse pointer acceleration and scroll wheel acceleration via the command line with `defaults write .GlobalPreferences com.apple.[mouse|scrollwheel].scaling`: http://dolphm.com/disable-mouse-pointer-acceleration-and-scroll-wheel-acceleration-in-os-x/

Comment: @Dolph The scroll wheel has a dead zone in addition to the acceleration - spinning the scroll wheel slowly does not register at all. The scaling preference only removes the acceleration.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this the Mouse acceleration Prefpane, download it free here:

http://triq.net/articles/mouse-acceleration-preference-pane-mac-os-x

Comment: That let you tweak the mouse cursor acceleration, not the the acceleration of the scroll wheel

Answer (score 0):

The open-source MOS tool is a lightweight tool used to smooth scrolling and set scroll direction independently for your mouse on MacOS.

https://mos.caldis.me/

Answer (score -3):

System Preferences---Mouse

There you can speed up the scrolling speed.

Tracking Speed relates to how fast the mouse moves across the screen.

Good Luck!

Comment: You could enlighten Robert, and the rest of us…

Comment: I'll do it. *Acceleration* is, in this context, when the mouse cursor (or page, when scrolling) moves **farther** when you move your finger **faster**. For instance, as @thieum said in the original question, "When I turn the wheel slowly, it only scrolls pixel per pixel (or per two pixels) If I turn the wheel more quickly, it scrolls nearly line by line. There is a kind of scroll wheel acceleration where the amount scrolled for each wheel step depends on the rotation speed of the wheel."

Answer (score -3):

[**SmoothScroll** for Mac](https://www.smoothscroll.net/) fixes this problem (you can disable acceleration or give your own parameters). Even better it makes [scrolling animated](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-3aF-4p_vKo) between wheel ticks so you get a smooth experience.

By paying for it you ensure that there's somebody out there who cares about the mouse scrolling experience on Macs.

(disclaimer: I am the developer)