# How to disable scroll acceleration in macOS Monterey

Tags: mouse, macos

After updated to MacOS 12.0 (Monterey), the annoying scrolling acceleration is back. And I can't scroll down with my Logitech Master MX1/MX2/Vertical.

I tried these solutions:

- https://github.com/emreyolcu/discrete-scroll
- zsh

```
defaults write .GlobalPreferences com.apple.scrollwheel.scaling -1
# Then I re-logged in and defaults read .GlobalPreferences com.apple.scrollwheel.scaling returns 1
defaults write .GlobalPreferences com.apple.scrollwheel.scaling 0
```

- [USB Overdrive](https://www.usboverdrive.com/)

And none of these works.(all from question: [How to disable scroll acceleration in macOS Sierra?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/253111/how-to-disable-scroll-acceleration-in-macos-sierra/273193))

I think it's a very basic setting and I don't want to pay for it.

Is there anything I can do? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Disabling acceleration is free in [Smooze](https://smooze.co/) and does work in Monterey (I'm the developer)

Toggle the "Animate Scroll" to Off and you're good to go.

Comment: Tested, and it works with the non-pro version. I'll test the stability later.

Comment: Tested for 10 days. All works nicely! No ads, correct functionality. Accepted and upvoted this answer.

Comment: Update: There is actually a menu bar icon after the testing period. So I uninstalled it.

Comment: This app really works!