# Scrolling does not register each click of the wheel

Tags: mouse, macos

Whenever I scroll using my mouse, my computer does not register the small, individual clicks of the scroll wheel. I have to scroll much faster to make anything happen.

I have tried this with two different mice, the Razer Death Adder and Logitech G403, same problem.

Computer specs: iMac, Late 2012, 10.12.1

Answer (score 0):

This site is very helpful and I discovered this post: [Change the mouse wheel scrolling acceleration](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/23189/change-the-mouse-wheel-scrolling-acceleration)

It's exactly what I needed!